# Show all closed Area 51 proposals

Tags: feature-request, area-51, closed-proposals

Some closed Area 51 feature requests are [still visible](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/17829/criminal-minded) but many [are](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18808/unix-commands-and-shell-scripts) [hidden](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18281/ask-babelfish). Why not show **all** closed requests so that, when someone tries to start a similar one, we can simply say, "this one probably won't work because this one also failed" - to avoid having the same discussions over and over again.

Related question: why are some visible and some hidden anyway?

Comment: Probably worth noting here that topics aren't *necessarily* relevant to outcome: some users are better than others at not getting their proposals deleted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close proposals **are** shown. The proposals you cited were *deleted*, not closed... by the original author.

Comment: The [FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) indicates SE will also delete inactive proposals: "Inactive proposals that do not receive any activity for one month are subject to deletion." The deleted proposal message adds: "Occasionally, proposals may be removed from Area 51 for reasons of moderation: spam, off topic, abuse, etc." Presumably the former is a change of policy since this answer was posted.